# why is Redis not using all three servers?

Tags: load-balancing, redis

What should happen, is something like in the attached screenshot, where keys go to different servers. However, we have a situation where one node in our cluster 25000 keys and each of the other two have about 15 keys.

Is there anyway Redis could be doing this, or are the application teams simply hitting individual redis servers instead of the cluster?[image]